# JAVASCRIPT- Como hago para que me acumule las etiquetas data-precio cuando pulso Producto1 o Producto2?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML> <html>
 <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <script> function IndicarDistancia(laId){//Crear una referencia del elemento HTML con la id que se pasa por parámetro
   var miDiv=document.getElementById(laId); //Obtener el valor de atributo 'data-precio' de la referencia miDiv
    var attr=miDiv.getAttribute('data-precio'); //Obtener una referencia del elemento con id="precio"
    var miContenedor=document.getElementById('precio'); //Introducir en miContendor el precio correspondiente del producto
    miContenedor.innerHTML='El precio es '+ attr; 
 }</script> 
</head>
 <body> <!--Cada button tiene un valor en data-precio y al hacer clic se ejecuta la función IndicarDistancia a la que se le pasa por parámetro la id del button correspondiente --> 
  <button data-precio="100€" id="uno" onClick="return IndicarDistancia('uno')"> Producto1</button>
  <button data-precio="50€" id="otro" onClick="return IndicarDistancia('otro')"> Producto2</button> <div id="precio"></div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Explicao un poco mas tu pregunta, esta algo amplia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ir acumulando el precio deberías almacenar el acumulado en una variable para ir sumando el precio del producto pulsado.

Para poder convertirlo a número sin problemas sería preferible que en la propiedad `data-precio` estuviera simplemente el número, ya añadirás el símbolo del euro al mostrar los datos en pantalla.

Otra posible mejora es añadir el controlador del evento por código en lugar de en el código HTML (en la propiedad `onclick`). Así te ahorras el tener que ir haciéndolo uno a uno. Y en caso de querer cambiarlo en un futuro te resultará mucho más fácil.

En el ejemplo que te pongo a continuación he omitido también el paso del `id` como argumento, ya que puedes acceder al elemento pulsado a través de la palabra reservada `this`.

```js
var precioTotal = 0;

// Suma precio del producto al total
function IndicarDistancia(){
  //Obtener el valor de atributo 'data-precio' del botón
  var attr = this.getAttribute('data-precio');
  // Sumar al precio total
  precioTotal += parseInt(attr);
  //Obtener una referencia del elemento con id="precio"
   var miContenedor=document.getElementById('precio');
   //Introducir en miContendor el precio total
   miContenedor.innerHTML='El precio es '+ precioTotal + '€'; 
}

var botones = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-precio]');
botones.forEach(boton=> boton.addEventListener('click', IndicarDistancia));
```

```html
<!--Cada button tiene un valor en data-precio y al hacer clic se ejecuta la función IndicarDistancia a la que se le pasa por parámetro la id del button correspondiente --> 
  <button data-precio="100" id="uno"> Producto1</button>
  <button data-precio="50" id="otro"> Producto2</button> <div id="precio"></div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, Asier. La verdad es que intente poner lo de la variable y tal, pero me ponía el NaN, pero eso fue por no poner el parseInt()... despistado yo xD. Muchas gracias ;)